# Spring mvc tiles without controller

Tags: spring, tiles

I try to mapping tiles definitions without method of controller but DispatcherServlet cannot find definitions without method of controller. 
Example:

Into tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="/test" template="/WEB-INF/pages/dump/test.jsp">
</tiles-definitions>
```

If I create controller with method, in this case the page will be showed:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/test"} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexAnonimous (){
   return "/test";
}
```

If I remove this then DispatcherServlet cannot find it.
I use java config.

WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class ApplicationConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setConfigLocation("com/ica/config");
        rootContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext.class - my application context.

WebMVC:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"********"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[]{    
                "/WEB-INF/pages/tiles.xml"
        });
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }
}
```

My log without method of controller

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:136) - Request '/test' matched by universal pattern '/**'
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:194) - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /test; Attributes: [permitAll]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:310) - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: D03A4E7DF41A3EF4AA8B1160678CED79; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AffirmativeBased.java:65) - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@b3abed, returned: 1
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:215) - Authorization successful
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:227) - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (FilterChainProxy.java:323) - /test reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (DispatcherServlet.java:845) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/test]
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:297) - Looking up handler method for path /test
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:305) - Did not find handler method for [/test]
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:169) - Matching patterns for request [/test] are [/**]
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:194) - URI Template variables for request [/test] are {}
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:124) - Mapping [/test] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@a866a8] and 1 interceptor
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (DispatcherServlet.java:931) - Last-Modified value for [/test] is: -1
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:304) - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (DispatcherServlet.java:1018) - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (FrameworkServlet.java:996) - Successfully completed request
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) - Chain processed normally
 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:97) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I can use another view resolver but it will work for only not tiles pages.
Please suggest me, what i should do for mapping definition without controller method.

Comment: Override the `addViewControllers` and add the name of the views for the urls you want to render. Or register a `UrlFilenameViewController` as a default controller, this takes the URL and transforms it into a view name.

Comment: UrlFilenameViewController calls tiles for rendering page after transoforming into a view name? Please give simple example how to configure UrlFilenameViewController if it can works with definitions of tiles.

Comment: No... Nor does any other controller. The view name is passed to the `ViewResolver`, that is how view resolving works.

Comment: Can you help me understand how to work it all.

Comment: When request come to server dispatcher try to find method, when method was fined and return name of page, viewResovler find this page according viewClass like in my example. When i use UrlFilenameViewController how it will work?

Comment: That is explained in the documentation. As I mentioned it simply returns a viewname based on the incoming URL (strips the extension when there is) and uses the remainder of the URL as a view name.